# Maths - Calculate Time Required to Process Requests

Tags: multithreading, math

I am trying to come up with a formula to calculate time required as per following configuration:

It takes 40 seconds to process each request. Server allows 3 requests per IP address per second.

If we use 50 proxies to process 200 requests, how much time will be required to complete all requests? I need the formula where number of requests and number of proxies can be variables.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not programming related.

Comment: @Nick This is actually related to programming. I am trying to calculate the execution time of the code.